# In toast-ui/react-image-editor, not able download the image on download click

Tags: reactjs, react-image-crop

When I click on the download button it is taking me to the new blank page with the image, but  in the API examples from the documents, its downloading on click, to the local storage, and for this in git its telling me to use file-saver to download the file, but I am not able to download with the file-saver, so can any one help me to download directly on  download button click to local storage with the edited image.
[Attached the code file picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qta7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to install the file-saver module and include

`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

in your code file

I don't think this is documented, but it work as of Oct 2022